# less than < sign not working with dates pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, date

Code
Input code to get dataframe between dates (Start date and end date)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_random = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
df_random['order_date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2010', 
periods=len(df_random), freq='D')
start_date = pd.to_datetime(2000-1-20).date()
end_date = pd.to_datetime(2000-12-31).date()
mask = (df_random['order_date'] >= start_date) & (df_random['order_date'] < 
 end_date)
df_random.loc[mask]
```

This code returns empty df

Dataframe df_random looks like this

```
                 0         1            2
date            
2000-01-01  0.694131    0.757274    0.920751
2000-01-05  0.472744    0.561246    0.112840
... ... ... ...
2000-07-17  0.005491    0.401239    0.936657
2000-07-18  0.952284    0.188398    0.198886
```

**Issue at hand**

The problem is that `[df_random['order_date']<end_date]` returns null array and hence the whole code where I should get rows between the two dates doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Problem is with your range and search values - you are starting with 2000 and asking anything less than 2010. If you fixed it it will work. Of course you will have to fix the quotes first in the start and end dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the quotes on these two lines:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2000-1-20').date()
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31').date()
```

Also, comparison between `pd.Timestamp` and `date` will be removed in the future. Right now you should get a warning. Leaving them as Timestamps are fine:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2000-1-20')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2000-12-31')
```

Comment: Yes i missed it. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure your statement about comparisons is correct. With 0.25.3 you either get a `TypeError` trying to compare a pd.Timestamp with a string: `pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01') < '2014-01-01'`, or no such issue when you compare a Series of `datetime64ns` with a string: `pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01')) < '2014-01-01'`

Comment: Even after adding inverted commas with the date the code is not working